# Custom surround with function

Tags: visual-studio-2012, shortcut, surround

I wan't to create **custom surround with function** in Microsoft Visual Studio 12.
How can i do it?
My custom custom surround with function should do this:

```
**"some text"** //I mark the text and do the function
This happens:
console.log(**"some text"**);
```

Also, is it possible to do it on a keyboard shortcut (like ***Ctrl + w***)?
Many thanks.